just audio package issue with notification
Just audio and just audio background packages were used, but there's an issue with adding a notification feature. When the user presses the stop button from the notification, if the user is on the player screen, the screen should pop up. This worked, but on the third attempt, when I entered, the player screen would automatically pop up and the music would start playing in the background until i stopped it from notification. "I used WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) instead of init." Stream build has been used so that changes can be caught at runtime
i looking to fix this isssue or find alternative ways to address the issue
